# Notation for second derivative of vector argument

Tags: notation

In my work I use derivatives of a scalar function f of a (column) vector argument x. I use the notation  $\frac{df}{dx}$ for the row vector first derivative, as well as, $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$ for the second derivative matrix. I have been strongly suggested by my advisor that this is not an appropriate notation and I should use $\frac{d^2f}{dxdx^T}$ instead. However, what should I do with third derivative then?

Comment: Intuitively, the shape of the derivative is the transpose of the shape that appears in the derivative "denominator", if you remove the $d$'s. $x$ is a column vector, and the first derivative is a row vector. $xx^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and the second derivative is the same. What do you want the third derivative to be, exactly? That would give you a hint as to where to look for an answer.

Comment: I tend to use $Df$, $D^{2}f$ etc. Or $D_{\boldsymbol{x}}f$, $D_{\boldsymbol{xx}}f$ etc. I think those are both notations used in Evans Partial Differential Equations.

Comment: @Arthur That's the point. I would have to use some kind of $\frac{d^3f}{dxdx^Tdx^*}$ where "multiplication" by $dx^*$ produces this three dimensional matrix. That would need introducing a lot of far-fetched notation. I wonder why simple $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ is not fine. Maybe I could use $\frac{d^3f}{dx\otimes dx\otimes dx}$ but this is not a mathematical thesis, so this may look pretentious.

Comment: @Ali That is an idea, however I already have a lot of D's in my notation already.

Comment: Define  $\,\partial_k = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\,$ and $\,\partial_{ij}=\partial_{i}\partial_{j}\;$ then the first, second, and third derivatives of $f$ can be written as $$\partial_{i}f\quad\partial_{ij}f\quad\partial_{ijk}f$$ Furthermore, the tensorial character of each derivative is made clear by the number of indices that it carries, i.e. the first is a vector, the second is a matrix, etc. At the same time, each indexed quantity is, by itself, a **_scalar_** component of the underlying derivative.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use it, this is solved by index notation (if not, then feel free to disregard this answer). In that case, the derivatives are simply
$$
\frac{df}{dx^i},
\frac{df^2}{dx^idx^j},
\frac{df^3}{dx^idx^jdx^k},
\cdots
$$
where $i,j,k$ are simply indices into the components of the $x$ vector.

In index notation, an upper index corresponds to the entries what you would normally consider a column vector, and a lower index corresponds to the entries of a row vector. A matrix has one upper and one lower index, and anything with more than one index either up or down isn't really representable in regular matrix-and-vector arithmetic (something with two upper indices, for instance, has in a sense two column dimensions and no row dimensions rather than one column dimension and one row dimension).

The upper indices in the derivative "denominator" are flipped and considered overall to be lower indices. Your teacher's desire to write $\frac{df^2}{dxdx^T}$ is, in this framework, considered a misguided attempt at consolidating two indices of the same kind into the familiar matrix, even though it's not entirely right (it can still be written down as an $n\times n$ table, but calling it a matrix isn't entirely right).

Comment: Thank you, the indexed notation you suggest might be okay. What do you think of $dx\otimes dx$ in the denominator? Do you agree that $dx^2$ is not appropriate?